# How to generate an image in javascript and convert it to png in IE7 (no html5 canvas and no server-side work)

Tags: javascript, vector-graphics

I want to create an image with javascript: draw lines, arcs, text, etc on some canvas like object and then convert it (in the client) to base-64 png string.

I know I can do it using html5 canvas (using canvas.toDataUrl("image/png")) but I need something that will work in IE7/IE8 as well.

The solution has to be completely in the client side, so taking an SVG, sending it to a server and than convert it with Apache Batik will not work for me.

I've found something that converts a bitmap (2d pixel array) into png - http://www.xarg.org/2010/03/generate-client-side-png-files-using-javascript/ 
so if there's some library that can generate the bitmap (or have some getPixelAt(x,y) functionality) from some sort of vector graphics data, that could be helpful.

Thanks,
Yoav

Comment: You can try excanvas to provide html5 canvas support for IE - http://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/

Comment: I've looked at explorer canvas. It looks like I can't export the canvas to png (like I can in the regular canvas) which I must.  was I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

You can try [fabricjs](http://fabricjs.com/).
It uses canvas, but is compatible with IE7/8(thanks to the Excanvas library) and has all the functionalities you're looking for.

It lacks a little in terms of documentation, but Kangax, the developer is quite active here and on the project [Google group](http://groups.google.com/group/fabricjs), so any doubt should be quickly resolved.

Comment: Looks promising, I'll check it out.

Comment: This doesn't work, unfortunately. Excanvas doesn't support toDataUrl(), which is the way to export the canvas into a base64 string.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a solution as well. The original javascript pnglib is quite nice but doesn't compile without errors on modern javascript environments. I've fixed the errors, converted it to ES6, and used typed-array to make it faster. Have a look:

https://github.com/IjzerenHein/pnglib-es6